# HTML 5 input type submit does not get passed as a parameter to the controller

Tags: java, forms, html, input, submit

I have a form with two submit buttons specifying a particular action value in HTML 5.

I want to get the value of either action1 or action2 (whichever is submitted).

```
<input type="submit" name="action2" value="action1"/>
<input type="submit" name="action1" value="action2"/>
```

Server side:

```
ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors){
String act1 = request.getParameter("action1");
String act2 = request.getParameter("action2");
}
```

Both act1 and act 2 are null. And when I debug, multipartParameters.keySetdoes not contain action1 and action2. This was not an issue in HTML 4. Is there a new way of doing this in html 5 ? Aside from using hidden fields..

Comment: HTML5 doesn't change anything here. Please show us the HTML of the submit buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formaction tag which will specify the url sent when the submit is clicked (overrides the form's action attribute)

if you are using spring 3 mvc (annotations) map each action request url to a method

if you are using spring 2 mvc (xml)

1. specify urls in the dispatcher to the controller
2. use request.getRequestURI then parse the url to determine the action